# Marionette js View parse data from html and render

Tags: backbone.js, marionette

I have layout

```
<div id="region">
<h1>Header</h1>
<ul class="items">
    <li>Number = 1</li>
    <li>Number = 2</li>
    <li>Number = 3</li>
</ul>
</div>
```

This render from backend
How to take data from the markup and render only new ItemView and remove those which are not in the json file

```
    class Collections extends Backbone.Collection
          initialize: ->
            console.log 'Collections init'


    class NowListning extends Marionette.CompositeView
          template :  _.template("<h1>Header</h1> <ul class='items'></ul>")
          itemView: NowListningItem
          itemViewContainer: '.items'
          initialize : ->
            console.log 'init:: View: Local -> NowListning'



   class NowListningItem extends Marionette.ItemView
          template :  _.template("<%= text %>")
          tagName: "li"     

   domData = []
        $('items li').each ->
          item:
            text: $(this).text()
          domData.push(item)

   collections = new Collections(domData)
        nowListning = new NowListning
        collections.fetch
          url: 'items.json'
```

If I create region and call Show method it changes CompositeView, but I want to update only the list, without a title

```
json 
[
 {
   "text": "Number = 3"
 },
 {
   "text": "Number = 4"
 }
]
```

And I want see

```
<div id="region">
    <h1>Header</h1>
    <ul class="items">
        <li>Number = 3</li>
        <li>Number = 4</li>
    </ul>
    </div>
```

Comment: json file? could you please append its src?

Comment: @Evgeniy Т.е у меня уже отрисован блок с бека и я не хочу его перерисовывать, а просто обновить данные коллекции и удалить старые itemView и добавить новые

Comment: Аха, понял - на всякий случай поясню - надо запихнуть коллекцию в дата атрибут - тогда на ините вьюхи ее можно легко спарсить. Когда придет время fetch, коллекцию можно reset-нуть. Тем самым отрендерится обновленная коллекция.

Answer (score 0):

To get data from markup you can parse html with Jquery, but i dont recomend do it. 
Better way is to add data attribute to html hode you receive from server:

for example :

```
<div id="region" data-collection='[{ "id" : 1, "text": "Number = 1" }, { "id" : 2, "text": "Number = 2" }, { "id" : 3, "text": "Number = 3" }]'>
    <h1>Header</h1>
    <ul class="items">
        <li>Number = 1</li>
        <li>Number = 2</li>
        <li>Number = 3</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

So when you render a collectionView - you can easily get initial collection. (on initialize for example).

Later, the you call .fetch() collection will be merged with json result. .fetch() has few merge behaviors - you can choose suitable for you, in this case i think 'reset'

You can also checkout [Derick's article](http://lostechies.com/derickbailey/2011/09/26/seo-and-accessibility-with-html5-pushstate-part-2-progressive-enhancement-with-backbone-js/) about similar problem.